Google OAuth 2.0 says invalid request for redirect
Testing with Google OAuth API, when I attempt to test the log in it returns error 400:Invalid Request. Prior to this I encountered an error with the redirect url not being absolute, which I fixed. After this the error 400 came up when I try to login with google.
I believe it is because the url is in my own machine's directory, which would be invalid if placed in the url bar under the domain. The issue is that I don't know how else I would refer to the directed file as an absolute path without using my own directory.
The redirect is declared as
$redirectUri = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Doubler/index.php';

And the page to login is:
<html>
    <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
</html>
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user_token'])) {
  header("Location: C:/xampp/htdocs/Doubler/index.php");
}
  echo "<a href=".$client->createAuthUrl().">Login with Google here!</a>";
?>

The directory for the website is:
https://i.sstatic.net/5tUDvyHO.png
The error comes up as:
Error 400: invalid_request
Request details: redirect_uri=C:/xampp/htdocs/Doubler/index.php flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow 

This could be a very simple solution, but I'm very unfamiliar with php.

header("Location: C:/xampp/htdocs/Doubler/index.php"); this should not be the full file path. put header("Location: index.php"); or whatever is the URI instead

First try using URI not URL, it should work!
header("Location: index.php");
Try using localhost like this :
header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/Doubler/index.php");
OR
header("Location: http://localhost/Doubler/index.php");
And if using Domain then
header("Location: https://whateverdomain.com/index.php");
